# How to make a key from an array of length n

Tags: python, json, list

I am trying to generate a dictionary in python that will later be converted to a JSON object.

I have a list of elements ['element1','element2',...'elementn'] that I want to use as the key.

With the following list:

```py
list1 = ['thing1','thing2',...'thingn']
list2 = ['element1','element2',...'elementn']
```

I want to make the following JSON object:

```
x = {
    'thing1' : {
        'thing2' : {
            ....
                'thingn': {}
        }
    },
    'element1' : {
        'element2' : {
            ....
                'elementn': {}
        }
    }
}
```

So that I can access x as such:

```
x['thing1']['thing2]...['thingn']
```

And add new data like this:

```
x['thing1']['thing2]['newdata']
```

Since the final JSON object will be hierarchical and the data will be added later, I wanted to iterate through the list of keys and generate the hierarchy as described above.

Answer (score 1):

It use `for` loop to get element and create dictionary and it use `start` to get nested dictionary to create next dictinary in next loop.

**EDIT:** I changed name `start` to `node` which better describe what is in this variable. It is used to move deeper in this structure like moving from node to node in tree or graph.

```
x = {}

list1 = ['thing1','thing2','thingn']
list2 = ['element1','element2','elementn']

node = x  # starting node
for item in list1:
    node[item] = {}    # create new sub-dictionary
    node = node[item]  # move to new sub-dictionary

node = x  # starting node
for item in list2:
    node[item] = {}    # create new sub-dictionary
    node = node[item]  # move to new sub-dictionary

print(x)

print(x['thing1']['thing2']['thingn'])

x['thing1']['thing2']['newdata'] = "Hello World!"
print(x['thing1']['thing2']['newdata'])
```

---

**EDIT:** the same as function

```
def add(start_node, levels):
    node = start_node      # starting node
    for item in levels:
        node[item] = {}    # create new sub-dictionary
        node = node[item]  # move to new sub-dictionary
    #return node


x = {}

list1 = ['thing1','thing2','thingn']
list2 = ['element1','element2','elementn']

add(x, list1)
add(x, list2)

print(x)
print(x['thing1']['thing2']['thingn'])

x['thing1']['thing2']['newdata'] = "Hello World!"
print(x['thing1']['thing2']['newdata'])
```

Using `.split('.')` you can use string `'element1.element2.elementn'`

```
add(x, 'element1.element2.elementn'.split('.'))
```

---

**EDIT:** Similar to get value

```
def add(node, levels):
    '''node: starting node'''
    for item in levels:
        node[item] = {}    # create new sub-dictionary
        node = node[item]  # move to new sub-dictionary
    #return node

def get(node, levels):
    '''node: starting node'''
    for item in levels:
        node = node[item]  # move to new sub-dictionary
    return node

x = {}

add(x, ['thing1','thing2','thingn'])
add(x, 'element1.element2.elementn'.split('.'))

x['thing1']['thing2']['newdata'] = "Hello World!"
print(x['thing1']['thing2']['newdata'])

print( get(x, ['thing1', 'thing2', 'newdata']) )
print( get(x, 'thing1.thing2.newdata'.split('.') ) )
```

Comment: I thought that the line "start = start[item]" would reinitialize the variable start, not just update the placement in the dictionary.

Comment: it lets me go deeper in this structure - like moving from node to node in tree or graph. I had problem to find good name for this variable but now I released that it should have name `node`.

Comment: Great! I reproduced the same in Ruby trying to figure out how it works, but I find it tricky :o. Can you add an explanation about how `x` is affected (in the first example)?

Comment: @iGian for list/dictionary Python uses reference in function - it doesn't create duplicated list/dictionary - so function works all time on original `x`. The same you will have with `y = x` - both variables keeps the same dictionary.